# Why is RS removing white spaces and how to preserve them?

Tags: amazon-redshift

We're migrating some old sql from Teradata to RS. I realized white spaces are being removed, why is it? and how may I preserver them?, thanks.

```
create table test99 ( a char(1), b char(1), c char(1));
insert into test99 values('*','*','*');
insert into test99 values('*',' ','*');
insert into test99 values('*','*','*');
select a||':'||b||':'||c from test99;

 ?column?
----------
 *:*:*
 *::*   <------- white space removed
 *:*:*
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`CHAR`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html#r_Character_types-char-or-character) is a fixed-length type. If you make a column `col1` a `CHAR(10)` and do:

```
INSERT INTO col1 VALUES ('cat');
```

This will be stored as: `'cat       '` to disk. All 10 bytes are used.

When you retrieve this data the `'cat       '` is retrieved and trimmed so you just get `'cat'` back. That trimming is done behind the scenes and it's the nature of the data type you are using.

It follows that when you store `' '` in that `CHAR(10)` column, what will be stored to disk will be `'          '` and when that value is retrieved it will be trimmed and what you will have left is `''`.

Instead use a `VARCHAR(1)`. It will take slightly more disk space, but you'll preserve your space.